# I over stayed in America as a child, would this affect applying as an international student in a different country?

Tags: usa, uk, study

When I was a child I entered America with my mom in 1992, but she doesn't have that passport anymore, so we had to get a new one. According to my mom I didn't need one back then because I was little. She was told that by the people at the airport.

She decided to overstay, but I didn't know that till I was older. But I did have the DACA status. I visited Canada successfully, would they allow me to enter the UK if I want to study there? Should I get a school agency or do I need an immigration lawyer for this?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. How old are you and what is your immigration status in the US now?